# how to get a region out of an image?

Tags: java, android

Lets say I use a black key jpg image as my layout in Java Code. Is there an easy way to get the region out of an image so I can use region.Contains() for my onTouchListener?

I've looked for them and there isn't any. I ask this because Im making a piano app and would like to get the regions of the images I use for the black/white keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than use an image, try rendering the piano keys yourself, and check if input is in the black key regions you render, rather than using an image.

If you really want to use the image, define the black regions within the image by hand.

Detecting regions in an image is a difficult problem, one you probably don't want to get into for such a simple purpose. If you had many images, or had to do this frequently it might be worth the headache but as you presumably don't... don't worry about it.

Comment: I agree. On top of that by rendering the piano in code you also have to define these regions you want to check against. Simplest case for experimentation is creating a custom view. Let it draw a rectangle in the center of the view and change color on touch event. For detecting the right key it's probably sufficient to just match the x-coordinate of the touch event and look in which "horizontal segment" of the piano it falls. That's a matter of dividing x by the piano key width.

Comment: Sorry english nore my first language but let me get this straight. You mean to lets say put the buttons on the layout then making the regions of the black/white keys myself on top of them. Then use onTouchListener with those regions? I assume this is how most piano apps do it, but none of them reveal their source code so cant be sure lol. If I finish this ill probably reveal the source code for everyone to see !. Thanks for the tip !

Comment: Yeah, you can put buttons on top, or you can create your "buttons" based on where the user clicks your `PianoView` follow me? That's what @NobuGames suggests as well I believe.

Comment: Hey thanks for your input man I really appreciate it. I'm now having trouble drawing the regions so they match the Buttons. Don't know how to get the coordinates. Sucks to be a newbie in android :D

Comment: No problem! Please open a new question. You'll get more support that way. The entire community is here to help.

Comment: Thanks. This is awesome I thought you guys would hate newbie questions ;P. Posted my new question :).

Comment: Yeah stack is great. People love answering questions. Just make them as direct and clear as possible. Users scoop them up for reputation. You'll have many people interested.